# a-text look-at not working as expected in a-marker

Tags: aframe

I've recently began learning A-frame to create some ar experiences and had some success with marker based things. Now I wanted to add a text to my model that is always facing me and that I can click and detect that click. I've first tried with Three.js by adding a THREE.Sprite to the model. The label is shown correctly and does rotate so that it is always facing me. Unfortunately I can't find a way to make it clickable. I found the way to make the model clickable but not what I attach to it. After this attempt I've tried by using a-text by doing something like:

```
<a-entity camera id="camera"></a-entity>

      <a-marker
        preset="hiro"
        id="markerA"
      >
        <a-entity
          id="model"
          gltf-model="#model"
          position="0 0 0"
          scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
        >
      
        </a-entity>
        <a-text 
        value="Hello world"
        
        height="100"
        width="400"
        color="black"
        scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
        position="0 0 0"
        look-at="#camera"
        ></a-text>
      </a-marker>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and the text does not rotate torwards the camera.
Any idea on what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Along tracking axis: feature-based</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="duomo" src="../assets/something.gltf">
            </a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-marker preset="hiro" markerhandler emitevents="true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" id="marker">
           
           
            <a-entity id="duomo" gltf-model="#duomo" position="0 0 0" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"></a-entity>
            <a-entity
                geometry="primitive: plane; height: auto; width: auto"
                material="color: blue"
                scale="0.8 0.8 0.8"
                position="0 0 0"
                look-at="[camera]"
                id="some-text"
                text="width: 4; value: This text will be 4 units wide."></a-entity>
        </a-marker>

        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

test.js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler', {

    init: function() {
        const animatedMarker = document.querySelector("#marker");
        const aEntity = document.querySelector("#some-text");

        // every click, we make our model grow in size :)
        animatedMarker.addEventListener('click', function(ev, target){
            const intersectedElement = ev && ev.detail && ev.detail.intersectedEl;
            if (aEntity && intersectedElement === aEntity) {
                const scale = aEntity.getAttribute('scale');
                Object.keys(scale).forEach((key) => scale[key] = scale[key] + 1);
                aEntity.setAttribute('scale', scale);
            }
        });
}});
```